# Where is the query and form in wp-login.php?

Tags: login

I have no HTTPS, and I would not like to use it yet on my blog. However, I need a way to secure my login page, so I want to encrypt the password with RSA before it gets sent. As I was not able to find a recent plugin, I need to do it myself. Where is the form so I can add javascript to encrypt, and where is the query so I can decrypt it?

Comment: stupid idea which show a total lack of understanding how SSL works and what are the weak security points in wordpress authentication scheme. In short it is totally not enough to "protect" your login, and your suggested protection do not actually protect even the login.

Comment: I ended up choosing to use Cloudflare SSL, but I believe that if implemented properly, it should work. The login is encrypted before it leaves the computer, so if someone were to intercept it, it would be encrypted.

Comment: no! reinventing protocols that people spent literally years inventing and ironing out the bugs is unlikely to end well. you are unlikely to even know what are the threat model https protects again (nothing personal, probably most of security people do not know as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook you will probably be most interesting in is [`wp_authenticate`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate).

> Codex: 
>   This action is located inside of [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon). In contrast to the wp_login action, it is executed before the WordPress authentication process.

That hook and wp-signon are defined in [*wp-incldues/user.php* line 10](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L10)

---

But *wp-includes/pluggable.php* has [`wp_authenticate()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate) and it can be overridden. It also provides a hook, [`authenticate`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate).

---

### The Form

The [log in form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) (the form itself) is defined in [*wp-includes/general-template.php* line 402](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L402)

You can hook the default `$args` with [`login_form_defaults`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_form_defaults) filter hook [defined on line 431](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L431)

The default `$args` for the form:

```
 $defaults = array(
                    'echo' => true,
                    // Default 'redirect' value takes the user back to the request URI.
                    'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                    'form_id' => 'loginform',
                    'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
                    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
                    'id_username' => 'user_login',
                    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
                    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
                    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
                    'remember' => true,
                    'value_username' => '',
                    // Set 'value_remember' to true to default the "Remember me" checkbox to checked.
                    'value_remember' => false,
            );
```

---

With [*root/wp-login.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-login.php)

You can enqueue scripts into the head via the action hook
`do_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts' );` on [line 90](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-login.php#L90)

---

### Considerations

There are other internal functions, like `wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password)` that follows `wp_signon` on *user.php*, that may be expecting or passing a text password.

A note on `$password` param in Codex of the `wp_authenticate_user` filter found in `wp_authenticate_username_password`:

> $password
>   (string) (optional) The user's password (plain text).

---

Hopefully `wp_signon` mentioned off the top can satisfy what you're after.

Comment: I will try it out as soon as I get a chance. I plan on decrypting it before any other functions, so there should be no problem.